# Rails: Finding users with at least 1 movie in common (user has_many movies through ratings)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Having some difficulty with an elegant way to solve this.

Users can rate movies 1 or 0. A user has many movies through ratings. I am trying to write an instance method to return a list of users who have at least one positive match in common (both rated movie 1).

e.g.

some_user.potential_matches  => returns list of users who rated at least one of some_user.movie_ratings.where(rating: 1)  as a 1

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one liner might do the job for you (it may need some tweaking to match your class names etc)

```
User.joins(:movies).where(movies: { id: Movie.joins(:users).where(users: { id: u }).joins(:ratings).where(ratings: { rating: 1 })})
```

When you're trying a query that is a bit more complicated I find it helpful to start at the end and work your way back

1) Find all movies with ratings == 1

`Movie.joins(:ratings).where(ratings: { rating: 1 })`

2) Replace all movies with only movies where user `u` has provided a rating. In your case since you're looking at an instance method for class `User` this will be `self`

`Movie.joins(:users).where(users: { id: u }).[INSERT QUERY FROM STEP 1 HERE]`

3) The last step is to find all users that have provided ratings for the movies returned by the query above

`User.joins(:movies).where(movies: { id: [INSERT QUERY FROM STEP 2 HERE] })`

[EDIT]
You can add `.uniq` at the end to return a unique set of users.

Comment: Perfect! Yeah I definitely need to brush up on my complicated queries.. That was really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `movie_id` and `user_id` in your `MovieRating` model when you built the association, please try the method here:

```
def potential_matches
  # find movie ids the user rated 1
  movie_ids = self.movie_ratings.where(rating: 1).map(&:movie_id)
  # find other users who rated 1 in those movies and get user_ids
  other_user_ids = MovieRating.where(rating: 1).where(movie_id: movie_ids).where.not(user_id: self.id).map(&:user_id).uniq
  # find those users with id 
  other_users = User.where(id: other_user_ids)

  return other_users
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your user class you can add this instance variable:

```
def users_with_rated_movies_in_common
  User.joins(:movies).where(movies: { id: movies }).where.not(id: self)
end
```

This basically grabs all users who have rated a movie, and the rated movies is a movie that the current user rated. Finally, we don't want to include the actual user.

You should be able to chain additional conditions onto the query.